# GeoJson "Not Well Formed" message in console, and appears undefined

Tags: javascript, json

Ive included the very end of my script below, where I'm trying to put a JSON file into a website using Ajax callback function. When I inspect the page, I'm seeing that the JSON file is not well formed and I can't seem to find an answer.  The webpage is also just showing that the JSON file is "undefined".

```
function debugCallback(response){
    
    var mydata;
    
    $("#mydiv").append('GeoJSON data: ' + JSON.stringify(mydata));
};


function debugAjax(){
    
    var mydata;

    $.ajax("data/MegaCities.GeoJSON", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            //mydata = response;
            debugCallback(mydata);
        }
    });

    $("#mydiv").append('<br>GeoJSON data:<br>' + JSON.stringify(mydata));
};

//$("#mydiv").append('GeoJSON data: ' + JSON.stringify(mydata));
if(typeof mydata === 'undefined') {
    console.log("undefined data")
} else {
    console.log("not undefined")
}
$(document).ready(debugAjax());
```

Comment: $.getJSON() try this one and http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/

Answer (score 0):

Avoid defining several functions and try just using this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax("data/MegaCities.GeoJSON", {
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(response){
            $("#mydiv").append('<br>GeoJSON data:<br>' + JSON.stringify(response));
        }
    });
});
```

Note that after we get response/data from ajax call, we proceed formatting as JSON.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `var mydata` and it is not defined so it is showing correct message `undefined` when you are passing it as value.

You should probably modify your code like this.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $.ajax({
    url: "data/MegaCities.GeoJSON",
    method: 'GET' ,
    aysnc: false,
    success: function(response){
        $("#mydiv").append('GeoJSON data:' +response);
    }
  });
});
```